# What JavaScript inconsistencies should I look out for?

Tags: javascript

I remember reading some "funny" examples once of weird results JavaScript can give when you, for example, add strings to numbers etc. Does anyone have any good examples or a link to the blog that I might have read them on? Which ones are likely to catch a programmer out in the real world?

Comment: Welcome to Programmers.  This questions does not meet the guidelines to asking questions on this site.  Please read the site's FAQ and edit it to meet more of those guidelines.  This question would fit under mindless social fun and one that creates lists for answers, both of which are off-topic.

Answer (score 8):

All the ones that are described in:

- the **[WAT](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)** talk (**warning:** this is **really fun!** - skip the Ruby part if you want),
- **[WTFJS](http://wtfjs.com/)**,
- a **[Collection of JavaScript Gotchas](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/182416/A-Collection-of-JavaScript-Gotchas)**,
- anything listed in resources in this [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/26891/3631),
- and any message that [JSLint](http://jslint.com) and [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) will spit or throw back at you.

Comment: That WAT talk is hysterical! Thanks for posting that

Answer (score 4):

The biggest gotcha in JavaScript is that the `==` operation performs type type coercion and should almost always be avoided.  Instead you should use the `===` to do a true boolean comparison.

For example, because of type coercion., `1 == true` is true, but `1 === true` is false. The `==` operator often hides type errors.

As a further illustration of true and false in this context these cases From [Crockford's The Elements of JavaScript Style](http://javascript.crockford.com/style2.html) are illustrative.

> ```
> '' == '0' // false    
> 0 == '' // true
> 0 == '0' // true
>
> false == 'false' // false 
> false == '0' // true
>
> false == undefined // false 
> false == null // false 
> null == undefined // true
>
> ' \t\r\n ' == 0 // true
> ```

Comment: I would not go so far as to say 'almost always' but yes, you should definitely prefer === unless you have a sensible use for ==

Answer (score 2):

I would go get a copy of Douglas Crockford's [Javascript the Good Parts](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596517742). Its probably the best book on Javascript in terms of pointing out the parts of javascript that are good and those tha should be avoided at all costs.